# How to remove duplicate value in an array Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, checkbox, multidimensional-array

I have checkbox (with selected value by user, checked ). So I need to edit this checkbox and get all the selected value into an array and send it to post.

**Html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of officeLIST">
  <div *ngIf ="item.officeID== userdata.officeID">
       <input #office type="checkbox" id="office" name="office" class="form-control" value="{{item.officeName}}" checked (click)="officeSelection($event,$event.target.value)" > {{(item.officeName== "" ? "--No data--" : item.officeName)}} 
 </div>
  <div *ngIf ="item.officeID!= userData.officeID">
     <input #office type="checkbox" id="office" name="office" class="form-control" value="{{item.officeName}}" (click)="officeSelection($event,$event.target.value)"> {{(item.officeName== "" ? "--No data--" : item.officeName)}}
 </div>
</div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"(click)="updateOffice(userData.officeID)"> Save </button>
```

**Click function (to add selected value and to remove unselected  value)**

```
 officeSelection(event: any, value) {        

        if (event.target.checked === true)
        {
               this.officeArray.push(value);
        } 
        else {
            this.officeArray.splice(this.officeArray.indexOf(value), 1);

        }
    }
```

**Update Function**

```
updateOfficeDetail(officeid) {

if(officeid= 1)
{    
         this.officeArray.push('stars dept');
}   
else if(officeid= 2)
{            

         this.officeArray.push('moon dept');
}
else
{          
     this.officeArray.push('Sun dept');

}
```

}

**Problem is**
if I update the data without changing current value of checkbox,eg: sun dept, 
 this **sun dept** will be **push** into **officeArray** . 
but if again I want to update the data by editing the checkbox(choose another value), so the previous selected value and current selected value will be push into this officeArray

if user did not edit the checkbox (just proceed with current selected value)>>>> the officeArray will look like this

> ["sun"]
>   **and if the user tried to update the checkbox by clicking one more checkbox, the array will look like this**
>   ["sun","moon","sun"]

I just want ["sun","moon"] in the officeArray. should i remove? or clear something?

I tried to do some research and a lot questions similar to me. but somehow all the solutions did not work for me. any idea?

Thank you

Comment: I'd like to help, but it's confusing the description, at least for me, can you add a plunk with the code? will be easier I guess

Comment: i see. but actually it is a big code so i just extract small part of it to see wats the problem...

Answer (score 1):

in your `if` expression in `updateOfficeDetail` method:

```
if(officeid === 1)
```

instead of

```
if(officeid= 1)
```

I recommand in your case to use `Set` instead of Array:

```
class youComponent{
 //...
 officeSelection(event: any, value) {        

    if (event.target.checked === true)
    {
        if(this.officeArray.includes(value.trim())){
           this.officeArray.push(value);
        }
    } 
    else {
        this.officeArray.splice(this.officeArray.indexOf(value), 1);
    }
}

updateOfficeDetail(officeid) {

if(officeid === 1)
{    
         if(this.officeArray.includes('stars dept')){
             this.officeArray.push('stars dept');
         }

}   
else if(officeid === 2)
{            
       if(this.officeArray.includes('moon dept')){
         this.officeArray.push('moon dept');
       }
}
else
{    
     if(this.officeArray.includes('Sun dept')){
         this.officeArray.push('Sun dept');
     }

} 
}
```

}

Comment: i tried but  for declaring it, i m getting generic type 'Set<T>' requires 1 type arguments. what argument should i put there?

Comment: it is working the same way how array worked. my stars dept keep added into list because it is the default value. so how do i make something like.. if this "stars dep" is already in officeArray then no need to add else we need to add. how the condition will look like?

Comment: @user3431310 see the update rewrite the code with Array

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using HashMap instead of array:

```
Map<String,String> officeMap = new HashMap<>();
officeMap.put(index, value);
```